# The minimum frequency for signal modulation

Tags: sampling, nyquist

I have a signal sampled with frequency 10 kHz. My spectrum is 1 kHz.
As far as I went, according to the Nyquist theorem I can module the signal with max. 5 kHz (1/2 of sampling frequency).
What's the minimum frequency I can use to modulate this signal?
How does it look on the graph?

Comment: please define what you mean by signal modulation specifically and what the characteristics are your sampled signal (what bandwidth does it occupy)?'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming amplitude modulation and 1 kHz baseband bandwidth:

1. The rightmost edge of the signal's spectrum must be less than 5 kHz. Then, the maximum carrier frequency is 4 kHz. The signal will occupy the band from 3 kHz to 5 kHz.
2. The leftmost edge of the spectrum must be larger than 0 Hz. Then, the minimum carrier frequency is 1 kHz. The signal will occupy the band from 0 to 2 kHz.

The, the carrier frequency must be larger than 1 kHz and smaller than 4 kHz.